# How do I make a web based Parser?

Tags: xml

Okay. in a nutshell, I need a parser that creates a module for a virtual tabletop program I use for RPG gaming. There is a certain way I need to format all the different variables for this to work.

I want to make a simple webpage that has all the textboxes each associated with the variables needed, and I want to simply fill those boxes in with the required information, hit a "generate" button and it spits out the information I need, with the correct formatting and tags I need to use. Here is an example of an entry:

```
<Aurumvorax>
    <librarylink type="windowreference">
        <class>npc</class>
        <recordname>..</recordname>
    </librarylink>
    <name type="string">Aurumvorax</name>
    <type type="string">N Small magical beast</type>
    <hd type="string">12d10+48</hd>
    <speed type="string">30 ft., burrow 10 ft.</speed>
    <ac type="string">23, touch 15, flat-footed 19; (+4 Dex, +8 natural, +1 size)</ac>
    <babgrp type="string">Base Atk +12; CMB +16 (+24 grapple); CMD 30 (42 vs. trip)</babgrp>
    <atk type="string">melee bite +18 (1d6+5 plus grab), 4 claws +18 (1d4+5 grab)</atk>
    <fullatk type="string">melee bite +18 (1d6+5 plus grab), 4 claws +18 (1d4+5 grab)</fullatk>
    <spacereach type="string">-- ft./0 ft.</spacereach>
    <specialattacks type="string">rake (4 claws +18, 1d4+5)</specialattacks>
    <senses type="string">darkvision 60 ft., low-light vision, scent, Perception +13</senses>
    <specialqualities type="string"></specialqualities>
    <skills type="string">Perception +13, Stealth +17</skills>
    <feats type="string">Bleeding Critical, Critical Focus, Great Fortitude, Improved Initiative,   Iron Will, Skill Focus (Perception)</feats>
    <environment type="string">temperate plains, hills or forests</environment>
    <organization type="string">solitary or pair</organization>
    <treasure type="string">standard</treasure>
    <alignment type="string">N</alignment>
    <leveladjustment type="string"> - </leveladjustment>
    <strength type="number">21</strength>
    <dexterity type="number">18</dexterity>
    <constitution type="number">18</constitution>
    <intelligence type="number">2</intelligence>
    <wisdom type="number">13</wisdom>
    <charisma type="number">11</charisma>
    <fortitudesave type="number">+14</fortitudesave>
    <reflexsave type="number">+12</reflexsave>
    <willsave type="number">+7</willsave>
    <hp type="number">114</hp>
    <init type="number">+8</init>
    <cr type="number">9</cr>
    <text type="formattedtext">
        <p>Powerful muscles ripple beneath the golden fur of this small yet fearsome eight-legged beast.</p>
        <p><b>XP:</b> 6,400</p>
        <p><b>Racial Modifiers:</b>-</p>
        <p><b>Grab (Ex):</b> An aurumvorax can grab a foe of up to one size category larger than itself. It gains +8 racial bonus on grapple attempts rather than the normal +4 racial bonus offered by the grapple ability.</p>
    </text>
</Aurumvorax>
```

From the example you can see things like `<name type="string">Aurumvorax</name>` I need to have the text boxes on site spit out the pieces between the <> and  tags. how exactly do I go about doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but "how would I do this" is something that can't be reasonably answered. Which part is it exactly that you don't know how to do? "Everything" and "I don't know how to start" are too broad.

Comment: Rob, you can start to learn how to input, edit and format code by clicking on the orange question mark by the post editor control, it's rather easy to spot (it's at the top right corner).